# How to export list of all ledgers which is under sundry debitors from tally using xml

Tags: tally

I want to export list of all ledgers which is under sundry debitors from tally using xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         <ENVELOPE>
            <HEADER>
                <VERSION>1</VERSION>
                <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
                <TYPE>Collection</TYPE>
                <ID>Ledgers</ID>
            </HEADER>
            <BODY>
                <DESC>
                    <STATICVARIABLES>
                        <SVEXPORTFORMAT>SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                    </STATICVARIABLES>
                    <TDL>
                        <TDLMESSAGE>
                            <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="Ledgers">
                                <TYPE>Ledger</TYPE>
                                <CHILDOF>$$GroupSundryDebtors</CHILDOF>
                                <BELONGSTO>Yes</BELONGSTO>
                                <NATIVEMETHOD>*/NATIVEMETHOD>
                            </COLLECTION>
                        </TDLMESSAGE>
                    </TDL>
                </DESC>
            </BODY>             
        </ENVELOPE>
```

Answer (score 0):

By mentioning type as `Ledger:Group` we can filter ledgers based on group by mentioning groupname in `childof` tag

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>Collection</TYPE>
        <ID>Ledgers</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                <!-- * Supports only xml format -->
                <SVFROMDATE TYPE="Date">{{Fromdate}}</SVFROMDATE>
                <SVTODATE TYPE="Date">{{ToDate}}</SVTODATE>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="Ledgers">
                        <TYPE>Ledger:Group</TYPE>
                        <Childof>Sundry Debtors</Childof>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>Address</NATIVEMETHOD>
                        <!-- * will fetch all fields if you want specific fields you can specify -->
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>Name,Parent,*</NATIVEMETHOD>
                    </COLLECTION>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```